# Concrete Example Illustrating the Interior Product

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, let $v \in V$ and let $\omega$ be an alternating $k$-tensor on $V$, i.e., $\omega \in \Lambda^{k}(V)$. Then, the *interior product* of $v$ with $w$, denoted by $i_{v}$, is a mapping
$$
i_{v}:\Lambda^{k}(V)\rightarrow \Lambda^{k-1}(V)
$$
determined by

$$
(i_v \omega)(v_1, \dots, v_{k-1}) = \omega(v, v_1, \dots, v_{k-1}).
$$

My understanding of this, which is probably far from complete, is that the interior product basically provides a mechanism to produce a $k-1$-tensor from a $k$ tensor relative to some fixed vector $v$. I'm trying to understand however what the interior product actually means and how it is used in practice. Therefore, my question is, *Can anyone provide example(s) illustrating computations and/or physical examples that will shed light on its purpose?*

Also, the interior product seems to be somewhat (inversely?) related to the exterior product in that an exterior product takes a $p$-tensor and a $q$ tensor and makes a $p+q$ tensor and therefore is an "expansion". The interior product, on the other hand, is a contraction but always produces a tensor of degree one less than you started out with. So, secondly, *What is the precise relation between the interior and exterior products*?

Unfortunately, the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) page is of little help here and I can't find a reference that clearly explains these things.

Comment: Just nitpicking: you can identify elements of $\bigwedge^k$ with alternating k-tensors only in characteristic 0.

Comment: @Alexei the question *is* tagged differential geometry `:-)`

Comment: For a physical example of the use of the interior product: that is how one can geometrically define the "electric" and "magnetic" parts of an electromagnetic field given by the Faraday tensor. It also shows conveniently how electric and magnetic fields change under Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me give another illustration of how the interior and exterior products are related. This particular case, however, works not on *differential geometry*, but requires *Riemannian geometry*.

Given a metric $g$, denote by $\langle,\rangle$ the extension of its inner (not interior) product to forms. The metric $g$ induces an identification between the vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$, via the operators $v\mapsto v^\flat$, where

$$ v^\flat(w) = \langle v,w\rangle $$

($v^\flat \in V^*$ is a linear functional on $V$, and here we define it by its action on $w\in V$)

Then we have the nice property for $\eta\in\Lambda^{k-1}(V),\tau \in \Lambda^k(V)$, and $v\in V$ that

$$ \langle v^\flat \wedge \eta, \tau\rangle = \langle \eta,(i_v)\tau \rangle $$

showing how the interior and exterior products are actually *adjoint* with respect to the metric inner product.

A similar statement can be made by appealing to the Hodge-star operator associated to a Riemannian metric. Up to a constant multiplier $C$ (whose form depends a bit on your conventions, and which depends on the dimension and the degree of the forms), you have that

$$ (i_x)\tau = C *(x^\flat\wedge *\tau) $$

where $*$ is the Hodge star operator.

Comment: Very nice example

Comment: @WillieWong How do you actually prove that $\langle v^\flat \wedge \eta, \tau\rangle = \langle \eta,(i_v)\tau \rangle$. It must not be hard but I just don't see it right now

Comment: @EternalBlood: probably the simplest is to write everything out in a basis. Note of course that for this to be an equality and not an equality up to multiplicative constant, some care is probably required in defining the correct normalization for the wedge/interior products.

Comment: @EternalBlood I've proven it on my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a partial answer to my own question, specifically the part asking for a concrete example illustrating computational aspects of the interior product.

Let the vector space in question be $\mathbb{R}^3$ endowed with the ordered basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ and let $e^1, e^2, e^3$ be the relative cobasis. Here, we can think of the cobasis as just ordinary vectors that satisfy $e^i(e_j) = \delta^i_j$ or consider them as linear functionals on the dual space $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ that satisfy the same relations.

Now, suppose  $\omega \in \Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is given by $\omega = e^1 \wedge e^2$ and let $v = e_1$. Then, for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we can then compute the interior product as follows:

$$
(i_v \omega)(x) = \omega(v, x) = (e^1 \wedge e^2)(e_1, x) = e^1(e_1)e^2(x) - e^1(x)e^2(e_1) = e^2(x)
$$

Therefore $i_v \omega = e^2$

Next, keep the same $\omega$ but let $v = e_2$. Then,

$$
(i_v \omega)(x) = (e^1 \wedge e^2)(e_2, x) = e^1(e_2)e^2(x) - e^1(x)e^2(e_2) = -e^1(x)
$$

So $i_v \omega = -e^1$

Finally, it is also easy to see by inspection that if $v =e_3$ then $i_v \omega = 0$

Computations for other values of $\omega$ proceed similarly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this will completely satisfy your questions, but I think the interior product is a neat way to induce orientations. To give an [orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Orientation_of_differential_manifolds) on an $n$-manifold with boundary $M$ is the same as giving a nowhere-vanishing $n$-form $\Omega$. If $H \subset M$ is a hypersurface and $N$ is a transverse vector field along $H$ (so $N\colon H \to TM$, such that $N_x \in T_xM$ and $T_xM = N_x + T_xH$ for $x \in H$), then $i_N\Omega$ restricts to an orientation form on $H$. If $H = \partial M$, then taking $N$ to be an outward-pointing vector field along $\partial M$ gives the usual orientation used in [Stokes's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem).

I don't have my copy with me, but a lot of this should be in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I've looked it up and it appears to be Proposition 13.12 on p 337. I have some work to do to completely understand the example but it's a start.

Comment: No problem. To me it's kind of an uninspiring example, since the usefulness of orientation forms at that point is that they spit out a sign. I wonder if there's something involving volume forms.

Answer (score 1):

Lie derivative, of course! It's even mentioned in the interior product wiki page. As for the relation to the exterior product, IMO you should look more on the exterior derivative for comparison.

But if you insist, for any $1$-form $\alpha$ and $k$-form $\omega$ and any vector $x$ we have $i_x (\alpha \wedge \omega) = \alpha(x) \omega$.

UPD: from purely algebraic standpoint, it is useful to consider Lie coalgebra structure on $V^*$: a linear mapping $\mathrm{d}: V^* \to \bigwedge^2 V^*$ extended to a graded anti-derivation. It is easy to see that by defining $\omega([x, y]) = \mathrm{d}\omega(x, y)$ we get Lie algebra structure on $V$.

So, interesting things must arise when we extend some $f: \bigwedge^2 V^* \to V^*$ to a graded antiderivation, right? Well, I can't answer that question, but I'm pretty sure that was the motivation :)

Comment: Of course? I'm glad that others find it to be so obvious. Notice though that Wikipedia page discusses the interior product within the context of manifolds and differential forms. Although I tagged the question with "differential geometry", the definition I provided, which comes from Jeff Lee's Manifolds and Differential Geometry, makes no reference to smooth infrastructure. Therefore, I'm hoping for an explanation in the more elementary context of multilinear algebra.

Comment: I didn't mean it's obvious, I meant it's useful for computing the Lie derivative. Is the interior product even used that much outside differential geometry?

Comment: As I'm just learning the concept I can't really say how it's used, but since it can be defined in a completely algebraic manner I would think that it would have some sort of meaning in that context. If its only purpose is to relate the exterior/Lie derivatives then I can accept that, but would be surprised if this was the case

Comment: I wouldn't call it its whole purpose, no.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by your answer. Did you read the question at all? You don't seem to address it (except for something in the second paragraph).

Comment: @Theo to be honest, the Lie derivative is also the first thing that popped in my head when a question asks about the interior product and makes an oblique reference to the exterior derivative.

Comment: @Willie: I agree about Cartan's formula - it also came to my mind first. However, the answer consisted first of just the first two lines, then the second paragraph was added, and then the Upd thing. None of these provide *examples of practical use* and I strongly doubt that someone having trouble seeing what the interior product does can grasp the points made here. Also, where do you see that oblique reference?  Because of the differential-geometry tag?

Comment: @Theo: yeah. Because in the browser title bar I see "differential geometry - Concrete example illustrating..." When I actually looked carefully at the question, of course, the exterior derivative isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\int{\operatorname{int}}
\def\ext{\operatorname{ext}}
\def\tsr{\operatorname{tsr}}$This post will answer the OP's question “what is the precise relation between the interior and exterior products?” It is Proposition 17. This result is the “nice property” that Willie Wong's explained in his answer, but without choosing a metric $g$. We will actually prove Willie Wong's formula in section 3 of this post by choosing a metric and bringing the situation to the general case. The good thing about all of this is that it is only linear algebra, and there is no smooth manifold theory. I've been unable to find the statement of Proposition 17 in any book, so I would be grateful if anyone could give a reference in case they know some.

### 1. Pairings and dualities over a field

Proposition 17 shows that “$\ext_v$ is the adjoint of $\int_v$ with respect to the pairing $\langle -, -\rangle :\Lambda V\times \Lambda V^* \to k$.” Before arriving to this result, we are going to dive into the theory of [pairings and dualities over a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_system), which can be regarded as a subtheory of linear algebra. We will build enough theory to prove that such an adjoint for $\ext_v$ is unique. We won't directly use all the theory we are going to develop, but I think that it is instructing to see this minimal amount to put things in context.

> **Definition 1.** As defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_system#Definition,_notation,_and_conventions), a *pairing* over a field $k$, or a *$k$-pairing*, is a triple $(V,W,b)$, where $V$ and $W$ are $k$-vector spaces and $b:V\times W\to k$ is a bilinear map. From a pairing we get induced linear maps
> \begin{align*}
> L_b:V&\to W^* \qquad\qquad R_b:W\to V^*\\
> v&\mapsto b(v,-), \qquad\quad\quad \,\; w\mapsto b(-,w).
> \end{align*}
> The pairing $(V,W,b)$ is said to be *non-degenerate* if $L_b$ and $R_b$ are both injective. A *dual system*, *dual pair* or *duality* over a field $k$, or a *$k$-duality*, is a non-degenerate pairing over $k$.
>
> The duality $(V,W,b)$ is *finite-dimensional* if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.
>
> A morphism of $k$-pairings $\varphi:(V_1,V_2,b)\to (V_1',V_2',b')$ is a pair $\varphi=(\varphi_1,\varphi_2)$, where $\varphi_i:V_i\to V_i'$ is a $k$-linear map, for $i=1,2$, such that $b'(\varphi_1(v_1),\varphi_2(v_2))=b(v_1,v_2)$ for all $v_1\in V_1$, $v_2\in V_2$. A morphism of $k$-dualities is a just a morphism of $k$-pairings.

*Remarks 2.*

1. The $k$-pairings form a category $\mathsf{Prng}_k$ which has the category of $k$-dualities $\mathsf{Dlty}_k$ as a full subcategory.
2. The isomorphism of $k$-pairings $(V,W,b)\cong(W,V,b')$, where $b'(w,v)=b(v,w)$, is natural.
3. If $(V,W,b)$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-duality, then $\dim V=\dim W$, for injectivity of $L_b$ and of $R_b$ implies $\dim V\leq\dim W^*=\dim W$ and $\dim W\leq\dim V^*=\dim V$.

*Examples 3.*

1. If $k=\mathbb{R}$, then from a real inner product space $(V,\langle -,-\rangle)$ we obtain a real duality $(V,V,\langle -,-\rangle)$.
2. The $k$-pairing $\langle -,-\rangle:V\times V^*\to k$ defined by $\langle v,f\rangle = f(v)$ is a non-degenerate: On the one hand, $\langle -,f\rangle = f$; whereas on the other hand if $0=\langle v,-\rangle$, then $f(v)=0$ for all $f\in V^*$. Thus, if we take a basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$, and we consider the associated linearly independent system $\{e_i^*\}\subset V^*$ (which is a basis if $\dim V<+\infty$), writing $v=v^ie_i$, we get $0=e_i^*(v)=v^i$, so $v=0$. For this reason, $(V,V^*,\langle -, -\rangle)$ or $(V^*,V,\langle -, -\rangle)$ is called the *canonical $k$-pairing* of the vector space $V$.
3. Let $V$ a $k$-vector space. Then the pair of maps $\operatorname{ev}:V\to V^{**}$, where $\operatorname{ev}(v)(f)=f(v)$, and $\operatorname{id}:V^*\to V^*$ form a natural morphism of canonical $k$-pairings $(V,V^*,\langle -,-\rangle )\to (V^{**},V^*,\langle -, -\rangle)$. For $V$ finite-dimensional, this is a natural isomorphism.

> **Definition 4.** A $k$-subpairing of a $k$-pairing $(V,W,b)$ is a morphism $(\varphi,\psi):(V',W',b')\to(V,W,b)$ of pairings such that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are injective. If $(V',W',b')$ is non-degenerate, it is called a $k$-subduality of $(V,W,b)$.

The proof of the following lemma is left as an exercise.

> **Lemma 5.** Let $(V,W,b)$ and $(V',W',b')$ be $k$-pairings and let $\varphi:V\to V'$ and $\psi:W\to W'$ be linear maps. Then $(\varphi,\psi)$ is a morphism of $k$-pairings $(V,W,b)\to(V',W',b')$ if and only if the following diagrams commute:
> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> V @>{L_b}>> W^* @. \qquad @. W @>{R_b}>> V^*\\
> @V{\varphi}VV @AA{\psi^*}A @. @V{\psi}VV @AA{\varphi^*}A \\
> V' @>>{L_{b'}}> (W')^* @. @. W' @>>{R_{b'}}> (V')^*
> \end{CD}$$
> and if and only if at least one of them commutes.

> **Corollary 6.** Let $(V,W,b)$, $(V',W',b')$ be isomorphic dualities. Then $L_b$ (resp., $R_b$) is injective if and only if $L_{b'}$ (resp., $R_{b'}$) is. In particular, $\mathsf{Dlty}_k$ is a replete subcategory of $\mathsf{Prng}_k$, meaning that two isomorphic $k$-pairings are $k$-dualities if and only if one of them is.

*Proof.* Immediate by inspection of the last commutative diagrams, since a linear map $T:A\to B$ being an iso implies, by functoriality, that the dual map $T^*:B^*\to A^*$ is an iso. $\square$

There is a simple situation in which for verifying that a pairing $(V,W,b)$ is non-degenerate is suffices to verify that at least one of $L_b$ or $R_b$ is injective.

> **Lemma 7.** Let $(V,W,b)$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-pairing with $\dim V=\dim W$. Then $L_b$ and $R_b$ are injective if and only if one of them is.

*Proof.* By last Corollary, we may assume that $V=W$, since if we pick an isomorphism $\varphi:W\cong V$, then $(1_V,\varphi):(V,W,b)\to (V,V,b')$ is an isomorphism of pairings, where $b'(v_1,v_2)=b(v_1,\varphi^{-1}(v_2))$, for $v_i\in V$.

The following diagrams commute:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>{L_b}>> V^* @. \qquad @. V @>{R_b}>> V^*\\
@V{\operatorname{ev}}VV @|  @. @V{\operatorname{ev}}VV @| \\
V^{**} @>>{R_{b}^*}> V^* @. @. V^{**} @>>{L_{b}^*}> V^* 
\end{CD}$$
where $\operatorname{ev}(v)(f)=f(v)$, for $v\in V$, $f\in V^*$. The map $\operatorname{ev}$ is an isomorphism (always true in the finite-dimensional case), and $L_b$ (resp., $R_b$) being injective implies it is bijective, by dimensionality. Thus, the claim follows since the dual functor reflects isomorphisms in finite-dimensional spaces ($T^*$ being an iso for a linear map $T:A\to B$ between finite-dimensional spaces implies $T$ is an iso). $\square$

> **Definition 8.** Let $(V,W, b)$, $(V',W',b')$ be $k$-pairings, and $A:V\to V'$, $B:W'\to W$ be linear operators. With respect to the pairings $b$ and $b'$, we say that $A$ is a *left adjoint* or a *left transpose* to $B$, or that $B$ is a *right adjoint* or a *right transpose* to $A$ if
> $$
> b'(Av,w')=b(v,Bw')
> $$
> for all $v\in V$, $w'\in W'$. If there is no place for confusion, sometimes we will just say $A$ is an adjoint or transpose for $B$ or $B$ is an adjoint or transpose for $A$. We will also say that the tuple $(A,B,b,b')$ is an *adjunction*. In the case where $(V,W, b)=(V',W',b')$, we will also say that the triple $(A,B,b)$ is an adjunction.

> **Lemma 9.** Let $(V,W,b)$, $(V',W',b')$ be $k$-pairings, and suppose that $R_b$ is injective (resp., suppose that $L_{b'}$ is injective). If a linear map $V\to V'$ (resp., a linear map $W'\to W$) has an right adjoint (resp., a left adjoint), then it is unique.

**Proof.** Suppose $B,\widetilde{B}:W'\to W$ are right adjoints for $A:V\to V'$, and let $w'\in W'$. Then, for all $v\in V$,
$$
b(v,Bw')=b'(Av,w')=b(v,\widetilde{B}w'),
$$
so $0=b(v,Bw-\widetilde{B}w)$. Since $R_b$ is injective, this implies $Bw=\widetilde{B}w$. Hence $B=\widetilde{B}$. Uniqueness of left adjoints is proven analogously. $\square$

*Examples 10.*

1. If $(V,V^*,\langle -,-\rangle)$ and $(W,W^*,\langle -,-\rangle)$ are the canonical $k$-pairings of the vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then a linear map $F:V\to W$ always has a right transpose, namely, $F^*$, since
   $$
   \langle v,F^*\omega\rangle=\langle Fv,\omega\rangle,
   $$
   for $v\in V$ and $\omega\in W^*$.
2. Let $V=k^n$ and suppose $\langle -, -\rangle : k^n\times k^n\to k$ is the standard bilinear form, $\langle v^ie_i,w^je_j\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n v^iw^i$. For any matrix $A\in k^{n\times n}$, the transpose operator of $A$ (right or left) is given by the transpose matrix.

> **Lemma 11.** Let $(V,W,b)$, $(V',W',b')$ be $k$-dualities and let $A:V\to V'$ be a linear map. A sufficient condition for the existence of a unique right adjoint of $A$ is that $R_b$ is injective and that $b'(A(-),W')\subset b(-,W)$, where
> \begin{align*}
> b'(A(-),W')&=\{b'(A(-),w')\mid w'\in W'\},\\
> b(-,W)&=\{b(-,w)\mid w\in W\},
> \end{align*}
> are subsets of $V^*$. Analogously, if $B:W'\to W$ is a linear map, a sufficient condition for the existence of a unique left adjoint of $B$ is that $L_{b'}$ is injective and $b(V,B(-))\subset b'(V',-)$.

*Proof.* Uniqueness follows from last lemma. We show existence of the right adjoint of $A$. Pick a $w'\in W'$. Then there is a (unique since $R_b$ is injective) $w\in W$ such that $b'(A(-),w')=b(-,w)$. Define $A^t(w')=w$. Then clearly
$$
b'(Av,w')=b(v,A^tw')
$$
for all $v\in V$. It remains to verify that $A^t:W'\to W$ is linear. Let $w_1',w_2'\in W'$. Then, for $v\in V$, we have
\begin{align*}
b(v,A^t(w_1'+w_2'))
&=b'(Av,w_1'+w_2')\\
&=b'(Av,w_1')+b'(Av,w_2')\\
&=b(v,A^tw_1')+b(v,A^tw_2')\\
&=b(v,A^tw_1'+A^tw_2').
\end{align*}
Thus, since $R_b$ is injective, it follows that $A^t(w_1'+w_2')=A^tw_1'+A^tw_2'$, so $A^t$ is additive. Homogeneity of $A^t$, i.e., $A^t(\lambda w')=\lambda A^tw'$, is proven similarly. Existence of the left adjoint of $B$ is done similarly. $\square$

> **Corollary 12.** For finite-dimensional $k$-dualities, unique adjoints always exist. Explicitly, if $(V,W,b)$ and $(V',W',b')$ are finite-dimensional $k$-dualities, then, with respect to $(b,b')$, any linear map $V\to V'$ has a unique right adjoint and any linear map $W'\to W$ has a unique left adjoint.

*Proof.* This is because $R_b$ and $L_{b'}$ being injective implies they are isos in the finite-dimensional case, so the conditions $b'(A(-),W')\subset b(-,W)=V^*$ and $b(V,B(-))\subset b'(V',-)=(W')^*$ from last lemma are always satisfied. $\square$

> **Lemma 13.** Let
> \begin{align*}
> (\varphi,\psi)  &:(V_1,W_1,b_1)   \to (V_2,W_2,b_2),\\
> (\varphi',\psi')&:(V_1',W_1',b_1')\to (V_2',W_2',b_2'),
> \end{align*}
> be isomorphisms of $k$-pairings. If $(A_1,B_1,b_1,b_1')$ is an adjunction, then so is $(A_2,B_2,b_2,b_2')$, where
> \begin{align*}
> A_2&=\varphi' A_1\varphi^{-1},\\
> B_2&=\psi B_1(\psi')^{-1}.
> \end{align*}

The proof is left as an exercise.

> **Lemma 14.** Let $(V_i,W_i,b_i)$, $i\in I$, be a family $k$-pairings. The $k$-pairing $\bigoplus_i(V_i,W_i,b_i):=(\bigoplus_i V_i,\bigoplus_i W_i,\bigoplus_i b_i)$, defined as $\left(\bigoplus_i b_i\right)(\sum_iv_i,\sum_iw_i)=\sum_ib_i(v_i,w_i)$, is non-degenerate if and only if $(V_i,W_i,b_i)$ is non-degenerate for all $i\in I$.

Beware that this construction is not a coproduct in the category of pairings. It's neither a product for $I$ finite.

*Proof.* ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $v\in V_j$ is such that $b_j(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in W_j$. Then $(\bigoplus_i b_i)(v,w)=b_j(v,w_j)=0$ for all $w\in\bigoplus_i W_i$, where $w_j$ is the $j$-th component of $w$. Thus $v=0$, and $L_{b_j}$ is injective. Proving that $R_{b_j}$ is injective is analogous.

($\Leftarrow$) Now suppose $v\in \bigoplus_i V_i$ is such that $\left(\bigoplus_i b_i\right)(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in\bigoplus_i W_i$. In particular, this implies $0=\left(\bigoplus_i b_i\right)(v,w)=b_j(v_j,w)$ for all $w\in W_j$, where $v_j$ is the $j$-th component of $v$. Thus $v_j=0$ and therefore $v=0$, so $L_{\bigoplus_i b_i}$ is injective. Proving that $R_{\bigoplus_i b_i}$ is injective is analogous. $\square$

> **Lemma 15.** Suppose $\operatorname{char} k\neq 2$ and let $(V_i,W_i,b_i)$ be finite-dimensional $k$-pairings, for $i=1,\dots,n$. The universal property of the tensor product induces a $k$-pairing $\bigotimes_i(V_i,W_i,b_i)=\left(\bigotimes_iV_i,\bigotimes_iW_i,\bigotimes_ib_i\right)$ by $(\bigotimes_ib_i)(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n,w_1\otimes\cdots\otimes w_n)=b_1(v_1,w_1)\cdots b_n(v_n,w_n)$ that is non-degenerate if $(V_i,W_i,b_i)$ is non-degenerate for all $i$. The converse is true if $V_i,W_i\neq \{0\}$.

*Proof.* We prove it for $n=2$. The proof for the general case is the same.

We prove the converse first. Denote $(V_1,W_1,b_1)=(V,W,b)$ and $(V_2,W_2,b_2)=(V',W',b')$ and suppose that $b\otimes b'$ is non-degenerate. Suppose $v\in V$ is such that $b(v,w)=0$ for all $w\in W$. Since $V'\neq\{0\}$, pick $v'\in V'\setminus\{0\}$. Then
$$
(b\otimes b')(v\otimes v',w\otimes w')=b(v,w)b'(v',w')=0
$$
for all $w\in W$ and $w'\in W'$. Thus $v\otimes v'=0$, since $b\otimes b'$ is non-degenerate. Hence, since $v'\neq 0$, $v=0$ and $L_b$ is injective. Showing injectivity of $R_b,L_{b'},R_{b'}$ is analogous.

To prove now $(\Rightarrow)$, note that we can assume $V_i=W_i$. Suppose then $(V,V,b)$ and $(W,W,b')$ to be finite-dimensional $k$-dualities and let's show that $(V\otimes W,V\otimes W,b\otimes b')$ is non-degenerate. Pick a $b$-orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$ and a $b'$-orthonormal basis $\{f_j\}$ of $W$ (for this we need $\operatorname{char}k\neq 2$). Then $b\otimes b'$ is non-degenerate since
$$
(b\otimes b')(e_i\otimes f_j,e_\ell\otimes f_m)=\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jm}.\qquad\qquad\square
$$

### 2. The adjoints of $\tsr_v$ and $\ext_v$

In the following, $V$ will always be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Denote $\Phi^p:T^pV^*\cong(T^pV)^*$ to the canonical isomorphism and write
$$
\tag{1}\label{eq2}
\langle t,\omega\rangle\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\langle t,\Phi^p(\omega)\rangle,
$$
for $t\in T^p V$, $\omega\in T^pV^*$. By Corollary 6, this defines a $k$-duality
$$
\tag{2}\label{p_dlty}
\langle -,-\rangle: T^pV\times T^pV^*\to k,
$$
since we have an isomorphism of $k$-pairings $(1_{T^pV},\Phi^p):(T^pV,T^pV^*,\langle -,-\rangle)\cong(T^pV,(T^pV)^*,\langle -,-\rangle)$.
For the pairing \eqref{p_dlty}, one can verify that
$$
\langle v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n,v_1^*\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n^*\rangle
=\langle v_1,v_1^*\rangle\cdots\langle v_n,v_n^*\rangle
$$ for any $v_i\in V$ and $v_i^*\in V^*$.

By Lemma 14, the $k$-dualities \eqref{p_dlty} extend to a $k$-duality
$$
\tag{3}\label{TV_dlty}
\langle -,-\rangle: TV\times TV^*\to k.
$$

For $t\in TV$, define an operator
\begin{align*}
\tsr_t:TV&\to TV\\
s&\mapsto t\otimes s.
\end{align*}
For $v\in V$ and $p\geq 1$, define
\begin{align*}
\tag{4}\label{eq:int_v}
\int_v: T^pV^*\to T^{p-1}V^*
\end{align*}
as $(\int_v\omega)(v_2,\dots,v_p)=\omega(v,v_2,\dots,v_p)$, for $\omega\in T^pV^*$ (for $p=1$ we understand $\int_v\omega=\omega(v)$). When $p=0$, define $\int_v:T^0V\to \{0\}$. Using the canonical isomorphisms $T^qV^*\cong(T^qV)^*$, the resulting map $\int_v:(T^pV)^*\to(T^{p-1}V)^*$ with $p\geq 1$ is expressed as $\int_v\omega=\omega\circ\tsr_v:T^{p-1}V\to k$, for $\omega\in(T^pV)^*$. In other words,
$$
\tag{5}\label{eq}
\langle t,\int_v\omega\rangle=\langle\tsr_vt,\omega\rangle,
$$
for $t\in T^{p-1}V$ and $\omega\in (T^pV)^*$. Thus, \eqref{eq} also holds for $t\in T^{p-1}V$ and $\omega\in T^p V^*$. As the linear maps \eqref{eq:int_v} assemble into an operator
$$
\label{eq:int_v_all}\tag{6}
\int_v:TV^*\to TV^*,
$$
relation \eqref{eq} also holds for every $t\in TV$ and $\omega\in TV^*$.
Equivalently, $\int_v$ is *the* right adjoint of $\tsr_v$ with respect to the $k$-duality \eqref{TV_dlty} (Lemma 9).

Let $\psi:\{0,1,2,\dots\}\to\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ be any function such that $\psi(0)=\psi(1)=1$. Recall that given $\alpha\in\Lambda^pV$ and $\beta\in\Lambda^qV$, one defines the exterior product $\alpha\wedge_\psi\beta\in\Lambda^{p+q}V$ as
$$
\alpha\wedge_\psi\beta=\frac{\psi(p+q)}{\psi(p)\psi(q)}A_{p+q}(\alpha\otimes\beta),
$$
where
\begin{align*}
A_p:T^pV&\longrightarrow\Lambda^pV\\
v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p
&\longmapsto\frac{1}{p!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_p}(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma) v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(p)}
\end{align*}
is the anti-symmetrization operator. Some authors define $\psi(n)=1$ to be constant, whereas others use the convention $\psi(n)=n!$. In general, one can check that $\wedge_\psi$ is associative and that
$$
\alpha_1\wedge_\psi\cdots\wedge_\psi\alpha_n
=\frac{\psi(p_1+\cdots+p_n)}{\psi(p_1)\cdots\psi(p_n)}A_{p_1+\dots+p_n}(\alpha_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\alpha_n),
$$
for $\alpha_i\in\Lambda^{p_i}V$. Henceforth we shall denote $\wedge=\wedge_\psi$ and keep the function $\psi$ to be general so the following arguments are valid for all possible normalizations of the exterior product that show up in the literature.

> **Exercise 16.** Given vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n\in V$ and covectors $v_1^*,\dots,v_n^*\in V^*$, show
> \begin{align*}
> \langle v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n,v_1^*\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n^*\rangle
> &=\frac{\psi(n)}{n!}\det(\langle v_i,v_j^*\rangle)=\langle v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n,v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n^*\rangle,\\
> \langle v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n,v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n^*\rangle
> &=\frac{\psi(n)^2}{n!}\det(\langle v_i,v_j^*\rangle).
> \end{align*}
> In particular, one has
> $$
> \langle v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n,\omega\rangle
> =\psi(n)\langle v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n,\omega\rangle,
> $$
> for $\omega\in\Lambda^nV^*$.

Since $\int_v(\Lambda^pV^*)\subset\Lambda^{p-1}V^*$ (check), the map \eqref{eq:int_v_all} restricts to a linear map
$$
\int_v:\Lambda V^*\to\Lambda V^*.
$$

For $\eta\in\Lambda V$, define
\begin{align*}
\ext_\eta:\Lambda V&\to\Lambda V\\
\nu&\mapsto\eta\wedge\nu.
\end{align*}

If we pass the subspace $\Lambda^pV^*\subset T^pV^*$ through the canonical isomorphism $\Phi^p:T^pV^*\cong(T^pV)^*$, we get an isomorphism $\Lambda^pV^*\cong(\Lambda^pV)^*\subset(T^pV)^*$. Thus, the canonical duality of $\Lambda^pV$, via \eqref{eq2}, induces a duality $(\Lambda^pV,\Lambda^pV^*,\langle -, -\rangle)$ (Corollary 6). By Lemma 14, these assemble into a duality
$$
\tag{7}\label{dlty_ext_pow}
\langle -, -\rangle :\Lambda V\times \Lambda V^* \to k,
$$
which is a subduality of \eqref{TV_dlty}. Indeed, the pairings $\langle -, -\rangle_{\Lambda V,\Lambda V^*}$, $\langle -, -\rangle_{T V,T V^*}$ are induced by the canonical pairings on $\Lambda^pV$ and $T^p V$, and in these last ones the former is a subpairing of the latter.

> **Proposition 17.** For $\omega\in(\Lambda^pV)^*$ and $v\in V$, we have
> $$
> \int_v\omega=\omega\circ\ext_v:\Lambda^{p-1}V\to k.
> $$
> Equivalently,
> $$
> \tag{8}\label{ext_adj_int}
> \langle\eta,\int_v\omega\rangle
> =\langle\ext_v\eta,\omega\rangle
> $$
> for $\eta\in\Lambda^{p-1}V$. This last equality is also valid when considering $\omega\in\Lambda^pV^*$, and, hence, also valid for all $\eta\in\Lambda V$ and $\omega\in\Lambda V^*$.

In other words, $\int_v$ is *the* right adjoint of $\ext_v$ with respect to the duality \eqref{dlty_ext_pow} (Lemma 9).

*Proof.* It suffices to show \eqref{ext_adj_int} for a system of generators of $\Lambda^p V^*$ and of $\Lambda^{p-1}V$. Let $v_1,\dots,v_p\in V$ be vectors and $v_1^*,\dots,v_p^*\in V^*$ be covectors. Then
\begin{align*}
\langle\ext_{v_1}(v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p),v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p^*\rangle
&=\langle v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p,v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p^*\rangle\\
&=\langle v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p,v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p^*\rangle\psi(p),
&\text{by Exercise 16,}\\
&=\langle \tsr_{v_1}(v_2\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p),v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p^*\rangle\psi(p)\\
&=\langle v_2\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p,\int_{v_1}(v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p^*)\rangle\psi(p),
&\text{by \eqref{eq},}\\
&=\langle v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p,\int_{v_1}(v_1^*\wedge\cdots\wedge v_p^*)\rangle,&\text{by Exercise 16.}\square
\end{align*}

### 3. The adjoints of $\tsr_{v^\flat}$ and $\ext_{v^\flat}$

We are going to consider now a specialized case of the previous adjunctions that is relevant for differential geometry. Now, we are going to fix a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $g:V\times V\to k$. This gives us an isomorphism
\begin{align*}
L_g=R_g=(-)^\flat:V&\longrightarrow V^*\\
v&\longmapsto v^\flat=g(v,-)=g(-,v).
\end{align*}
Denote $(-)^\sharp: V^*\to V$ to the inverse of $(-)^\flat$.

Since the tensor algebra is a covariant functor, the maps $(-)^\flat: V
\rightleftarrows
V^*
:(-)^\sharp$ induce inverse algebra isomorphisms
$$
(-)^\flat: TV
\rightleftarrows
TV^*
:(-)^\sharp.
$$
The $k$-duality \eqref{TV_dlty} induces a $k$-duality
$$
\tag{9}\label{eq:dlty_TV_dual}
\langle -,-\rangle:TV^*\times TV^*\to k.
$$
Namely, the one that makes the following diagram commute:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
TV^*\times TV^* @>{\langle -,-\rangle}>> k \\
@V{((-)^\sharp,1_{TV^*})}VV @| \\
TV\times TV^* @>>{\langle -,-\rangle}> k  
\end{CD}$$

Thus, by Lemma 13, the adjunction $
(\tsr_v,
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{TV,TV^*})
$ induces an adjunction
$$
((-)^\sharp\circ\tsr_v\circ(-)^\flat,
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*}).
$$
We claim that $(-)^\sharp\circ\tsr_v\circ(-)^\flat=\tsr_{v^\flat}$. Proving this amounts to show commutativity of the diagram
$$
\tag{10}\label{eq:diag_tsr_flat}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
TV @>{\tsr_v}>> TV \\
@V{(-)^\flat}VV @VV{(-)^\flat}V \\
TV^* @>>{\tsr_{v^\flat}}> TV^*  
\end{CD}$$
By the universal property of the tensor algebra, it suffices to show commutativity for elements of $V\subset TV$. But this is trivial since $(-)^\flat:TV\to TV^*$ is an algebra homomorphism and so $(v\otimes w)^\flat=v^\flat\otimes w^\flat$. This shows that $
(\tsr_{v^\flat},
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*})
$ is an adjunction.

Imitating what we just did and *mutatis mutandis*, from the duality \eqref{dlty_ext_pow} we can obtain a $k$-duality
$$
\tag{11}\label{eq:dlty_lambda_V_dual}
\langle -,-\rangle :\Lambda V^*\times\Lambda V^*\to k,
$$
leveraging now on the fact that the exterior algebra assignment is a functor.

> **Claim 18.** The duality \eqref{eq:dlty_lambda_V_dual} is a subduality of \eqref{eq:dlty_TV_dual}.

*Proof.* We want to show that the upper triangle in the following [diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNSxbMSwxLCJrIl0sWzAsMCwiXFxMYW1iZGEgVl4qXFx0aW1lc1xcTGFtYmRhIFZeKiJdLFsyLDAsIlRWXipcXHRpbWVzIFRWXioiXSxbMiwyLCJUVlxcdGltZXMgVFZeKiJdLFswLDIsIlxcTGFtYmRhIFZcXHRpbWVzXFxMYW1iZGEgVl4qIl0sWzEsMiwiIiwwLHsic3R5bGUiOnsidGFpbCI6eyJuYW1lIjoiaG9vayIsInNpZGUiOiJ0b3AifX19XSxbMSw0LCIoKC0pXlxcc2hhcnAsMV97XFxMYW1iZGEgVl4qfSkiLDJdLFs0LDMsIiIsMix7InN0eWxlIjp7InRhaWwiOnsibmFtZSI6Imhvb2siLCJzaWRlIjoidG9wIn19fV0sWzIsMywiKCgtKV5cXHNoYXJwLDFfe1QgVl4qfSkiXSxbNCwwXSxbMSwwXSxbMiwwXSxbMywwXV0=) commutes:

[image]

For this, it suffices to show that the rest of the cells of the diagram commute. The left and right triangles commute by definition. The outer square commutes by naturality of the inclusion $\Lambda W\hookrightarrow TW$ (which amounts to naturality of the inclusions $\Lambda^pW\hookrightarrow T^pW$). Lastly, the lower triangle commutes because $\Lambda V\times\Lambda V^*\hookrightarrow TV\times TV^*$ is a subpairing, (see comments after \eqref{dlty_ext_pow}). $\square$

We then obtain an adjunction $
(\ext_{v^\flat},
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*})
$
from the adjunction
$
(\ext_{v},
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V,\Lambda V^*})
$. The analogous diagram for \eqref{eq:diag_tsr_flat} would now be
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda V @>{\ext_v}>> \Lambda V \\
@V{(-)^\flat}VV @VV{(-)^\flat}V \\
\Lambda V^* @>>{\ext_{v^\flat}}> \Lambda V^*  
\end{CD}$$
which can be seen to commute using the universal property of the exterior algebra: it suffices to verify commutativity for elements of $V\subset\Lambda V$. But we have $(v\wedge w)^\flat=v^\flat\wedge w^\flat$, for $(-)^\flat:\Lambda V \to \Lambda V^*$ is an algebra homomorphism.

As a conclusion to this post, we are going to describe in a more explicit way what the pairings $\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*}$ and $\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*}$ look like in terms of $g$, in a more explicit way.

If we apply Lemma 15 to $g$, we obtain a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form
\begin{align*}
T^pg:T^pV\times T^pV&\to k\\
(v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n,w_1\otimes\cdots\otimes w_n)
&\mapsto g(v_1,w_1)\cdots g(v_n,w_n).
\end{align*}
By Lemma 14, these assemble into a non-degenerate bilinear form
$$
Tg: TV\times TV\to k.
$$
On the other hand, we have an induced non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $g^\sharp:V^*\times V^*\to k$ given by $g^\sharp(\omega,\eta)=g(\omega^\sharp,\eta^\sharp)$, so we get another non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form
$$
Tg^\sharp: TV^*\times TV^*\to k.
$$

> **Claim 19.** It holds $\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*}=Tg^\sharp(-,-)$.

*Proof.* We want to show that the outer triangle of the following [diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNCxbMCwwLCJUVl4qXFx0aW1lcyBUVl4qIl0sWzAsMiwiVFZcXHRpbWVzIFRWIl0sWzEsMSwiVFZcXHRpbWVzIFRWXioiXSxbMiwxLCJrIl0sWzAsMSwiKCgtKV5cXHNoYXJwLCgtKV5cXHNoYXJwKSIsMl0sWzAsMiwiKCgtKV5cXHNoYXJwLDFfe1RWXip9KSIsMV0sWzIsMSwiKDFfe1RWfSwoLSleXFxzaGFycCkiLDFdLFsxLDMsIlRnIiwyLHsiY3VydmUiOjJ9XSxbMiwzXSxbMCwzLCJcXGxhbmdsZSAtLC1cXHJhbmdsZV97VFZeKixUVl4qfSIsMCx7ImN1cnZlIjotMn1dXQ==) commutes:

[image]

For this, in turn, it suffices to show that the three internal triangles commute. The upper triangle commutes by definition and the left triangle obviously commutes. We will verify then that the lower triangle commutes.

We must see that this lower triangle commutes for $k$-vectors paired with $k$-covectors in $TV\times TV^*$. First consider the case $k=1$. Let $v\in V$ and $\omega\in V^*$. Then
\begin{align*}
g(v,\omega^\sharp)&=g(-,\omega^\sharp)(v)\\
&=(\omega^{\sharp})^{\flat}(v)\\
&=\omega(v)\\
&=\langle v,\omega\rangle.
\end{align*}
Now let $v_1,\dots,v_p\in V$ and $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_p\in V^*$. Then
\begin{align*}
Tg(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p,
(\omega_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega_p)^\sharp)
&=Tg(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p,
\omega_1^\sharp\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega_p^\sharp)\\
&=g(v_1,\omega_1^\sharp)\cdots g(v_p,\omega_p^\sharp)\\
&=\langle v_1,\omega_1\rangle\cdots\langle v_p,\omega_p\rangle\\
&=\langle v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_p,
\omega_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\omega_p\rangle.&\qquad\square
\end{align*}

In particular, this shows that $\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*}$ is symmetric. Thus, since $
(\tsr_{v^\flat},
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*})
$ is an adjunction, so is $
(\int_v,
\tsr_{v^\flat},
\langle -,-\rangle_{TV^*,TV^*})
$.

Denote $\Lambda g=Tg|_{\Lambda V}:\Lambda V\times\Lambda V\to k$. The following is proven in a similar way as Exercise 16.

> **Exercise 20.** Given vectors $v_1,w_1,\dots,v_n,w_n\in V$, show
> \begin{align*}
> T^ng( v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n,w_1\otimes\cdots\otimes w_n)
> &=\frac{\psi(n)}{n!}\det(g( v_i,w_j))=T^ng( v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n,w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_n),\\
> T^ng( v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n,w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_n)
> &=\frac{\psi(n)^2}{n!}\det(g( v_i,w_j)).
> \end{align*}

Usage of claims 18 and 19 shows then that $\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*} =\Lambda g^\sharp(-,-)$. In particular, $\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*}$ is symmetric, and, thus, since $
(\ext_{v^\flat},
\int_v,
\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*})
$ is an adjunction, so is $
(\int_v,
\ext_{v^\flat},
\langle -,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*})
$.

On the other hand, by the last exercise, for $\omega_1,\eta_1,\dots,\omega_n,\eta_n\in V^*$, we have
$$
\langle\omega_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega_n,
\eta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\eta_n\rangle
=
\frac{\psi(n)^2}{n!}\det(g(\omega_i^\sharp,\eta_j^\sharp)).
$$

Note that if we redefined the pairing $\langle-,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*}$ to be $\frac{n!}{\psi(n)^2}$ times the old pairing then we would get rid of the normalization constant in the last equality and $(\ext_{v^\flat},\int_v,\langle-,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*})$ would still be an adjunction. In fact, there are authors that begin with a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ equipped with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $g$ on $V$ and then *define* the pairing $\langle-,-\rangle_{\Lambda V^*,\Lambda V^*}$ explicitly in this way. However, the adjunction is now not so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\doub\mathfrak
\newcommand\Ext{{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\MVects[1]{\mathop{{\textstyle\bigwedge}^{\!#1}}}
\newcommand\Blades[1]{\mathop{{\textstyle\bigwedge}^{\!(#1)}}}
\newcommand\lintr{\mathbin{{\lrcorner}}}
\newcommand\rintr{\mathbin{{\llcorner}}}
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin{{\rfloor}}}
\newcommand\rcontr{\mathbin{{\lfloor}}}
\newcommand\rev\widetilde
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\End{\mathrm{End}}
%\newcommand\pperp{\mathrel{{}_\circ\kern-0.75pt{\perp}_\circ}}
\newcommand\pperp{\mathrel\top}
\newcommand\G{\mathcal G}
\newcommand\Hyp{\mathcal H}
\newcommand\pstar{\mathop{*}}
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}
$It does not seem to me that any of the answers, including the accepted answer, actually answer the question.

Rather than alternating tensors, we will focus on the exterior algebra; these are not the same thing in non-zero characteristic, and in any case the exterior algebra viewpoint is both more appropriate and very geometric. Since you ask for applications, I will focus on $\R$ and at times assume the presence of a metric (i.e. symmetric bilinear form) denoted by $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_V : V\times V \to \R$. I will **not** necessarily assume that this form is non-degenerate.

## Setup

### Contractions

Before getting into applications, we make clear out conventions and notations by considering the natural form
$$
  \form{v^* + v, w^* + w} = v^*(w) + w^*(v)
$$
on $\doub W = V^*\oplus V$. This form is non-degenerate, and in fact comes directly from the sequence of natural isomorphisms
$$
  (V^*\oplus V)^* \cong (V^*)^*\oplus V^* \cong V\oplus V^* \cong V^*\oplus V.
$$
We extend $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ to all of $\Ext\doub W$ such that
$$
  \form{v^*_k\wedge v^*_{k-1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge v^*_1,\;
        v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_l}
    = \delta_{kl}\det\Bigl(v^*_i(v_j)\Bigr)_{i,j=1}^k.
$$
This extension is very natural, but I won't get into that here. Often you will see the convention of using $1,2,\dotsc, k$ instead of $k, k-1,\dotsc,1$; while it can be argued that the former is more geometric, the latter tends to be easier to work with algebraically especially together with what will be our conventions for the interior product. Note that $\Ext\doub W$ contains $\Ext V^*$ and $\Ext V$ as subalgebras, and in fact $\Ext\doub W \cong \Ext V^*\mathbin{\widehat\otimes}\Ext V$ as algebras where $\widehat\otimes$ is a graded tensor product.

Since $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ is non-degenerate, we can now define the **left** and **right interior products** ${\lintr}, {\rintr} : \Ext\doub W\times\Ext\doub W \to \Ext\doub W$ as the adjoints of the exterior product:
$$
  \form{\doub X\wedge\doub Y, \doub Z} = \form{\doub X, \doub Y\lintr\doub Z},\quad
  \form{\doub X, \doub Y\wedge\doub Z} = \form{\doub X\rintr\doub Y, \doub Z}.
$$
$i_v$ corresponds to $v\lintr$ where $\lintr$ is restricted to $V\times\Ext V^*$. It is easy to see from this definition that
$$
  \form{\doub X, \doub Y} = \form{\doub X\lintr\doub Y}_0 = \form{\doub X\rintr\doub Y}_0
$$
where $\form\cdot_0$ is the scalar (i.e. grade $0$) part of a multivector. These products are closely related: if $\rev{\doub X}$ is the *reversal* anti-automorphism (or *main anti-involution*) of $\doub X$ which reverses all exterior products and is the identity on vectors, then
$$
  \rev{\doub X\lintr\doub Y} = \rev{\doub Y}\rintr\rev{\doub X}.
$$
For this reason we will generally only state properties of the left interior product. Some key properties to be aware of are

1. $\doub v\lintr\doub w = \form{\doub v,\doub w}$ for $\doub v,\doub w \in \doub W$.
2. $\doub X\lintr\doub Y \in \MVects{k-j}\doub W$ if $k\geq j$ and $\doub X \in \MVects k\doub W$ and $\doub Y \in \MVects j\doub W$, and is zero if $k < j$. In particular, if $k = j$ we get a scalar.
3. The interior products make $\Ext\doub W$ into an $\Ext\doub W$-module:
   $$
     \doub X\wedge\doub Y\lintr \doub Z = \doub X\lintr\doub Y\lintr\doub Z.
   $$
4. Vectors give anti-derivations:
   $$
     \doub v\lintr\doub X\wedge\doub Y = (\doub v\lintr\doub X)\wedge\doub Y + \widehat{\doub X}\wedge(\doub v\lintr\doub Y)
   $$
   where $\doub v \in \doub W$ and $\widehat{\doub X}$ is the *grade involution* (or *main involution*) which is the homomorphism that negates all vectors.

We use the convention that $\wedge$ binds tighter than $\lintr$ or $\rintr$, and that $\lintr$ is right-associative and $\rintr$ is left-associative.

A metric $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_V : V\times V \to \R$ induces a linear map $\flat : V \to V^*$;
the universal property of $\Ext V$ extends this to a homomorphism $\Ext V \to \Ext V^*$.
This allows us to extend $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_V$ to $\Ext V$ via
$$
  \form{X, Y}_V = \form{X^\flat, Y}
$$
and to define the **left** and **right contractions** on $X, Y \in \Ext V$ as
$$
  X\lcontr Y = X^\flat\lintr Y,\quad X\rcontr Y = X\rintr Y^\flat.
$$
These contractions will be the form in which we apply the interior products.
While they are adjoints of the exterior product under $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_V$,
if this form is degenerate then they are not the *unique* adjoints.

### Clifford Algebras

Once we have a quadratic form $Q(v) = \form{v, v}_V$ we also immediately get a *Clifford algebra* $\Cl(Q)$. In short, this is the freest associative algebra generated by $V$ subject to the relations $v^2 = \form{v, v}_V$ for all $v \in V$. **The contractions on $\Ext V$ are merely the manifestation of $\Cl(V)$ in $\Ext V$.**

To elaborate a bit, we define an additional *Clifford product* $V\times\Ext V \to \Ext V$ via
$$
  vX = v\lcontr X + v\wedge X.
$$
This gives us a map $v \mapsto v(\cdot) : V \to \End(\Ext V)$ into the linear endomorphisms of $\Ext V$, and the universal property of Clifford algebras extends this to an algebra homomorphism $\psi : \Cl(Q) \to \End(\Ext V)$. The map $X \mapsto \psi(X)(1)$ is then a linear isomorphism $\Cl(Q) \cong \Ext V$. To illustrate, the Clifford product of $u + vw = u + \form{v,w}_V + v\wedge w$ for $u, v, w \in V$ and $X \in \Ext V$ would be
$$\begin{aligned}
  (u + vw)X
&= uX + vwX
\\
&= u\lcontr X + u\wedge X + v(w\lcontr X + w\wedge X)
\\
&= u\lcontr X + u\wedge X + v\lcontr w\lcontr X + v\wedge(w\lcontr X) + v\lcontr w\wedge X + v\wedge w\wedge X
\\
&= u\lcontr X + u\wedge X + v\wedge x\lcontr X + v\wedge(w\lcontr X) + \form{v,w}_VX - w\wedge(v\lcontr X) + v\wedge w\wedge X.
\end{aligned}$$

This is all to say that **the interpretation of the contractions and the interpretation of the associated Clifford algebra are strongly linked**. We will not speak too much about Clifford algebras because we are interested in *only* the contractions, but they will be mentioned briefly again. It is safe to say, however, that if you find yourself working with contractions and exterior products all at once then there is certainly a Clifford algebra waiting for your attention as well.

## Applications

The following are just some examples of the applications of $\lcontr$ and $\rcontr$.

### The Join Geometry of $\Ext V$

For $X \in \Ext V$, we will be interested in the kernel of $v \mapsto X\wedge v$ over $V$; denote this by
$$
  [X]^\wedge = \{v \in V \;:\; v\wedge X = 0\}.
$$
The exterior algebra can be characterized as the most general associative algebra where
$$\begin{aligned}
  &v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k = 0 &&\text{if }\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}\text{ is linearly independent},
\\
  &[v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k]^\wedge = \mathrm{span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\} &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $[0]^\wedge = V$. We will call such an element $v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k$ a *blade* and denote the set of $k$-blades by $\Blades kV$. In this way we identify subspaces of $V$ with blades. The blades $\Blades nV = \MVects nV$ where $n = \dim V$ play a particularly special role and are often called *pseudoscalars* since they are one-dimensional.

If $X, Y$ are blades, then in general we have
$$\begin{aligned}
  &X\wedge Y = 0 &&\text{if }\exists v \in V.\: v \in [X]^\wedge\cap[Y]^\wedge,
\\
  &[X\wedge Y]^\wedge = [X]^\wedge\oplus[Y]^\wedge &&\text{otherwise},
\end{aligned}$$
so $X\wedge Y = 0$ detects if $X$ and $Y$ intersect, and if not then $X\wedge Y$ models the "join" (i.e. span) of subspaces.

It is in this framework that we may interpret the contraction. Suppose we have a metric on $V$ and that $X, Y$ are blades representing subspaces which are non-degenerate with respect to the metric; then
$$\begin{aligned}
  &X\lcontr Y = 0 &&\text{if }\exists v \in [X]^\wedge.\: v\perp[Y]^\wedge,
\\
  &[X\lcontr Y]^\wedge = P_Y([X]^\wedge)^\perp\cap[Y]^\wedge &&\text{otherwise},
\end{aligned}$$
where $P_Y$ is the orthogonal projection onto $[Y]^\wedge$ and $\perp$ denotes orthogonality or the orthogonal complement. In words, $X\lcontr Y = 0$ detects whether or not $X$ is *partially orthogonal* to $Y$, and if not then $X\lcontr Y$ computes the unique subspace of $Y$ which is orthogonal to $P_Y(X)$. We can get *exactly* the projection by orthogonalizing again:
$$
  P_Y(v) = (v\lcontr Y)\lcontr Y^{-1} = (v\lcontr Y)Y^{-1}
$$
where $Y^{-1} = Y/Y^2 = Y/\form{Y, Y}_V$ is the Clifford inverse, and in the last equality we may replace the contraction with a Clifford product.

If we contract a pseudoscalar then the projection is trivial since pseudoscalars represent the entirety of $V$. So choose a *unit* pseudoscalar $I$, i.e. $\form{I, I}_V = \pm1$; there are exactly two of these, the other being $-I$. This amounts to a choice of orientation. We see that
$$
  [X\lcontr I]^\wedge = [X]^{{\wedge}\perp}.
$$
This is quite like the Hodge star. Actually
$$
  \rev X\lcontr I = \rev XI
$$
is **exactly** the Hodge star. This should make clear the following *duality*, valid for any pseudoscalar and written with the Clifford product to reduce clutter:
$$
  X\wedge(YI) = X\lcontr Y\,I,\quad X\lcontr(YI) = X\wedge Y\,I.
$$
Here we use the convention that the Clifford product binds weaker than any other product.

### The Meet Geometry of $\Ext V^*$

If we were to replace $V$ with $V^*$ in the above, we would get nothing interesting. So we look at what $V^*$ says about $V$: just as a vector represents an oriented line with magnitude, we will interpret covectors as oriented *hyperplanes* with magnitude. In particular, $v^* \in V^*$ represents the hyperplane $\ker(v^*)$. But recall that $v^*(v) = \form{v^*, v} = v^*\rintr v$. This suggests that we define
$$
  [X^*]^{\lintr} = \{v \in V \;:\; v\lintr X^* = 0\}.
$$
Rather than the joins of lines like in $\Ext V$, the blades of $\Ext V^*$ represent **intersections** of hyperplanes:
$$\begin{aligned}
  &v^*_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v^*_k = 0 &&\text{if }\{v^*_1,\dotsc,v^*_k\}\text{ is linearly dependent},
\\
  &[v^*_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v^*_k]^{\lintr} = \bigcap_{i=1}^k[v^*_i]^{\lintr} &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{aligned}$$
While the sum of two oriented, weighted lines
may be familiar via the sum of two vectors,
the sum of two hyperplanes is probably less familiar.
Suppose that $v, w \in V$ have equal weight
and that $v^*, w^* \in V^*$ have equal weight
(defining this precisely requires something norm-like, like a quadratic form).
Just as $v+w$ is a line
*contained in* the *span* of $v, w$ "half way between" them,
$v^* + w^*$ is a hyperplane
which *contains* the *intersection* of $v^*, w^*$
and is "half way between" them.
Just as $v+\alpha w$ is "closer" to $w$ for $\alpha > 1$,
$v^*+\alpha w^*$ is "closer" to $w^*$.
These two facts should give sufficient intuition for the sum of two hyperplanes.

Let
$$
  \Hyp = \{[v^*]^{\lintr} \;:\; v^* \in V^*\},\quad
  \Hyp_S = \{H \in \Hyp \;:\; S \subseteq H\}
$$
denote the set of hyperplanes of $V$
and the set of hyperplanes containing a subspace $S \subseteq V$,
respectively.
In general, for blades $X^*$ and $Y^*$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
  &X^*\wedge Y^* = 0 &&\text{if }\exists H\in\Hyp.\: [X^*]^{\lintr}\cup[Y^*]^{\lintr} \subseteq H,
\\
  &[X^*\wedge Y^*]^{\lintr} = [X^*]^{\lintr}\cap[Y^*]^{\lintr} &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus $X^*\wedge Y^* = 0$ tests whether $X^*$ and $Y^*$
are contained in a common hyperplane, and if not then $X^*\wedge Y^*$
models the "meet" (i.e. intersection) of subspaces.

Now suppose we have a metric on $V^*$.
We will say that hyperplanes corresponding to orthogonal covectors
are *$*$-orthogonal*, written $\pperp$.
A subspace $S \subseteq V$ is $*$-orthogonal to $H \in \Hyp$,
written $S\pperp H$, if $K \pperp H$ for every $K \in \Hyp_S$.
The $*$-orthogonal complement $S^{\pperp}$ of $S$
is the intersection of all such hyperplanes.
We then say that $S\pperp T$ for subspaces $S, T$
if $T^{\pperp} \subseteq S$ or $S^{\pperp} \subseteq T$.

Now let $X^*, Y^* \in \Ext V^*$ represent non-degenerate subspaces of $V$.
We have
$$\begin{aligned}
  &X^*\lcontr Y^* = 0 &&\text{if }\exists H\in\Hyp_{X^*}.\: H \pperp [Y^*]^{\lintr},
\\
  &[X^*\lcontr Y^*]^{\lintr} = P^*_{Y^*}([X^*]^{\lintr})^{\pperp}\oplus[Y^*]^{\lintr} &&\text{otherwise}.
\end{aligned}$$
$P^*_{Y^*}$ is the *$*$-orthogonal projection* onto $[Y^*]^{\lintr}$.
Of course we have
$$
  P^*_{Y^*}(v^*) = (v^*\lcontr Y^*)\lcontr (Y^*)^{-1}.
$$
This is defined by analogy to orthogonal projection:
given a non-degenerate subspace $S$,
for any oriented, weighted line (vector) $v \in V$
there are unique $v_S \in S$ and $v_\perp \in S^\perp$
such that $v = v_S + v_\perp$;
$v_S$ is then the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $S$.
Thus, for any oriented, weighted hyperplane $v^* \in V^*$
there are unique $v^*_S, v^*_{\pperp}$ with $S \subseteq [v^*_S]^{\lintr}$
and $S^{\pperp} \subseteq [v^*_{\pperp}]^{\lintr}$
such that $v^* = v^*_S + v^*_{\pperp}$;
$v^*_S$ is then the $*$-orthogonal projection of $v^*$ onto $S$.
To project an arbitrary subspace $T$ onto $S$,
project each hyperplane that contains $T$ and then take their intersection:
$$
  P^*_S(T) = \bigcap_{H\in\Hyp_T}P^*_S(H).
$$

As a simple example of $*$-orthogonal projection,
consider $\R^3$ with the standard metric.
This induces a metric on $(\R^3)^*$ via non-degeneracy.
Consider a plane $\pi$ and an non-orthogonal line $l$.
The orthogonal projection $P_\pi(l)$
can be visualized as rotating $l$ through the small angle it makes with $\pi$
in such a way that $l\oplus\pi^\perp$ is constant throughout the motion, until $l$ lies inside $\pi$.
The $*$-orthogonal projection $P^*_l(\pi)$
can be visualized as rotating $\pi$ through the small angle it makes with $l$
in such a way that $l^{\pperp}\cap \pi = l^\perp\cap \pi$ is constant throughout the motion, until $\pi$ contains $l$.

### The Poincaré Isomorphisms

Recall with a non-degenerate metric on $V$
and a chosen orientation represented with unit pseudoscalar $I \in \MVects nV$
that the Hodge star $\Ext V \to \Ext V$ is
$$
  \star X = \rev X\lcontr I.
$$
Without such a non-degenerate metric, we of course do not have a Hodge star.
However, the Hodge star actually descends from a more fundamental duality.
Choose any non-zero $I \in \MVects nV$
and choose the unique $I^* \in \MVects nV^*$
such that $\form{\rev I^*, I} = 1$.
We can then define the *Poincaré isomorphisms*
$I_\#, I^*_\# : \Ext V \to \Ext V^*$
and $I^\#, I^\#_* : \Ext V^* \to \Ext V$ by
$$\begin{aligned}
  I_\#(X) &= \rev X\lintr I^*, & I_\#^*(X) &= I^*\rintr\rev X,
\\
  I^\#(X^*) &= \rev X^*\lintr I, & I^\#_*(X^*) &= I\rintr\rev X^*.
\end{aligned}$$
There is essentially only one isomorphism: as the notation suggests,
the pairs $I_\#, I_\#^*$ and $I^\#, I^\#_*$ are dual,
and additionally the pairs $I^\#, I_\#^*$ and $I_\#, I^\#_*$ are inverses.
These isomorphisms are *grade reversing*, taking $k$-vectors to $(n-k)$-vectors.
It is easy to see that if we replace $I$ by $\alpha I$
for nonzero scalar $\alpha$
then each of these scales by $\alpha$ or $1/\alpha$.
In the presence of a non-degenerate metric
we get an isomorphism $\flat : V \to V^*$
which then extends to an algebra isomorphism $\Ext V \to \Ext V^*$;
the Hodge star $\star : \Ext V \to \Ext V$ is exactly
$$
  \star X = I^\#(X^\flat),\quad
  \star^{-1}X = [I_\#^*(X)]^\sharp
$$
where $\sharp = \flat^{-1}$.
Note that even if $\flat$ is not an isomorphism
the composition $I^\#\circ\flat$ still makes sense.

The Poincaré isomorphisms are *geometry preserving* in the sense that
$$
  [I_\#(X)]^{\lintr} = [X]^{\wedge}
$$
and similary for the others.
Thus we can transfer the meet geometry of $\Ext V^*$ to $\Ext V$
(or similarly the join geometry of $\Ext V$ to $\Ext V^*$) by defining
$$
  X\vee Y = I^\#(I_\#^*(X)\wedge I_\#^*(Y)).
$$
(Both the pairs $I^\#, I_\#^*$ and $I^\#_*, I^\#$
give the same definition of $\vee$).
Generically, we call such a $\vee$ the *regressive product*;
in the context of $\Ext V$ we call it the *meet product*,
and in the context of $\Ext V^*$ we call it the *join product*.
In terms of the Hodge star (when available)
$$
  X\vee Y = \star(\star^{-1}X\wedge \star^{-1}Y).
$$

Finally, the Poincaré isomorphisms show us that *regardless* of degeneracy
there is a sense in which a metric on $V$ induces a metric on $V^*$.
A metric $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_V$ on $V$
extends to a metric $(X, Y) \mapsto \form{\rev X, Y}_V$
on $X, Y \in \MVects {n-1}V$; then
$$
  (v^*, w^*) \mapsto \form{\rev{I^\#(v^*)}, I^\#(w^*)}_V
$$
is a metric on $V^*$.
While this metric is dependent on $I$,
all such metrics are equivalent as quadratic forms
and the induced notion of $*$-orthogonality is independent of $I$.
When $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_V$ is non-degenerate
this induced metric has the same signature;
however, in the presence of degeneracy it becomes quite different.
The $*$-metric induced by a metric of signature $(p,q,r)$
(number of positive-, negative-, zero-squaring orthogonal basis elements)
has degeneracy $p+q$ if $r = 1$ and is completely degenerate if $r > 1$.

### Rotational Intertia

A metric of signature $(n,0,0)$ is, of course,
natural for linear Euclidean geometry.
In physics, the (rotational, origin-relative) *inertia tensor*
is a linear function on bivectors $\mathcal I : \MVects 2V \to \MVects 2V$
which takes an *angular velocity bivector* $B$
to the corresponding *angular momentum bivector* $\mathcal I(B)$
for a given rigid body.
If the rigid body is composed of particles with position vectors $x_i$
and masses $m_i$, then the inertia takes the form
$$
  \mathcal I(B) = \sum_i m_ix_i\wedge(B\rcontr x_i).
$$
This can easily be extended to a continuous body
by replacing the sum with an integral.
See Section 3.4.4 of *Geometric Algebra for Physicists*
by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby for more detail.

### Projective Euclidean Geometry

A metric of signature $(n,0,1)$ on $V^*$
turns out to be the natural setting for $n$D projective Euclidean geometry.
This construction goes by the name of *Plane-based Geometric Algebra*
or less commonly *Projective Geometric Algebra*,
but both shorten to PGA and this acronym is the most common.

In PGA, as one would expect hyperplanes are represented by covectors in $V^*$;
however, we now get *all hyperplanes of Euclidean space*
and not just those that pass through a specific origin point.
There is also a unique hyperlane, *the hyperplane at infinity*,
corresponding to the span of covectors $v^*$ such that $\form{v^*,v^*} = 0$.
We then use the exterior product
to form all the other flat elements of Euclidean
as intersections of hyperplanes.
Thus a point is an $n$-vector, a line is a $(n-1)$-vector, etc.

Restrict now to the case $n=3$ and let $\pi, l, P$
be a plane, a line, and a point as represented in the exterior algebra,
and assume none of them are at infinity.
Here are some geometric interpretations of $\lcontr$:

- $\pi\lcontr P$ is the unique line orthogonal to $\pi$ passing through $P$.
- $(\pi\lcontr P)\lcontr P^{-1}$ (using the Clifford inverse)
  is the unique plane parallel to $\pi$ passing through $P$.
- $l\lcontr P$ is the unique plane orthogonal to $l$ passing through $P$.
- $(l\lcontr P)\lcontr P^{-1}$
  is the unique line parallel to $l$ passing through $P$.
- $\pi\lcontr l = 0$ if $\pi$ is orthogonal to $l$,
  and otherwise is the unique plane $*$-orthogonal to $\pi$ containing $l$.
- $(\pi\lcontr l)\lcontr l^{-1}$
  is the $*$-orthogonal projection of $\pi$ onto $l$
  with their intersection as origin;
  if they do not intersect, then it is the unique plane parallel to $\pi$
  containing $l$.

The regressive product $\vee$ is also significant and is maybe more immediately intuitable.
Let $P, Q$ be points, $l, m$ be lines, and $\pi$ be a plane.

- $P\vee Q = 0$ if $P$ and $Q$ are the same point, and otherwise is the line joining them.
- $P\vee l = 0$ if $P$ lies on $l$, and otherwise is the plane joining them.
- $P\vee\pi$ is the orthogonal distance from $P$ to $\pi$.
- $l\vee m = 0$ if $l$ and $m$ lie in a common plane, and more generally it is proportional to $\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle $l$ and $m$ would make if they were translated so as to intersect.

For a treatment of rigid-body mechanics using PGA, see [*May the Forque be with You!*](https://bivector.net/PGADYN.html) by Leo Dorst and Steven De Keninck. For more on PGA itself and its relationship with projective geometry, see [*Geometry, Kinematics, and Rigid Body Mechanics in Cayley-Klein Geometries*](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/items/12ff6379-bed1-451f-a2d6-0483bec32619) by Charles Gunn.

### Codifferentials

Briefly, a *differential form* $\omega$ on a differentiable manifold $M$
is defined by $\omega_x \in (\Ext T_xM)^* \cong \Ext T^*_xM$ for each point $x \in M$,
where $T_xM$ and $T^*_xM$ are respectively the tangent and cotangent spaces at $x$.
Given coordinates $x^i$, the exterior derivative of $\omega$ is simply
$$
  \dd\omega = \nabla\wedge\omega = \sum_i\dd x^i\wedge\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial x^i}.
$$

If we have a metric $\form{\cdot,\cdot}_M$ and hence a Hodge star, then the *codifferential* is
$$
  {\star^{-1}}\dd{\star}\omega
= (\nabla\wedge(\rev\omega I)\,I^{-1})^\sim
= (\nabla\lcontr\rev\omega\,II^{-1})^\sim
= \dot\omega\rcontr\dot\nabla.
$$
Here, $I \in \MVects nT^*M$ is the chosen volume form, $I^{-1}$ is its point-wise Clifford inverse,
Clifford products are taken point-wise, and the overdots $\dot\omega$ and $\dot\nabla$ clarify what $\nabla$ is being applied to.
We can take this a step further; since
$$
  \dot\omega\rcontr\dot\nabla = \nabla\lcontr\widehat\omega
$$
using the Clifford product we may write
$$
  \dd\omega + {\star^{-1}}\dd{\star}\widehat\omega
= \nabla\wedge\omega + \nabla\lcontr\omega = \nabla\omega.
$$
The expression $\nabla\omega$ is to be understood with the Clifford product.
Since the two terms on the LHS have different grades we can recover both from $\nabla\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but it certainly should be relevant to this discussion.  Andrew McInerney's excellent new book "First Steps in Differential Geometry" discusses the interior product of a (o, k) tensor field (always alternating according to the book's conventions) on pp. 169 - 171.

He gives 2 examples: 4.6.17 and 4.6.18

If any one understands how the result follows in 4.6.18 which "the reader may verify"  please inform me.