# Some pretty identities and adjoint of interior product of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Let $M$ be a riemannian manifold. For each $k\geq 0$, let $ \bigwedge^{k}(M, \mathbb R)=\bigsqcup\limits_{p\in M}\ \bigwedge^k(T^*_pM)$ denote the smooth bundle of ($k$-multilinear) alternating forms on $M.$

If $\alpha\in\bigwedge^{k-1}(M, \mathbb R), \beta\in\bigwedge^{k}(M, \mathbb R)$ and $v$ is a tangent vector, I want to prove that
$$(1)\qquad \qquad\langle\!\langle v^\flat \wedge \alpha, \beta\rangle\!\rangle = \langle\!\langle \alpha,v\lrcorner\beta\rangle\! \rangle,$$
where $v^\flat(w) := \langle v,w\rangle$ and $\langle\!\langle \,, \rangle\! \rangle$ denotes the [standard inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Inner_product) on $\bigwedge^{k}(M, \mathbb R)$.

That is, $\lrcorner$ and $\wedge$ are actually *adjoint operators* with respect to $\langle\!\langle \,, \rangle\! \rangle$. I have seen this statement at several isolated places, but I haven't seen a proof of this (maybe it's not hard at all and I'm just not getting it, so it would be cool to know why this formula actually holds).

Also, if $\gamma\in\bigwedge^{k}(M, \mathbb R)$ and $v, w$ are tangent vectors, I want to see why the following *Clifford relation* holds
$$(2)\qquad\qquad v^\flat \wedge (w\lrcorner\gamma)+w\lrcorner(v^\flat\wedge \gamma)=\langle v, w \rangle\gamma.$$
Finally, [Willie Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1543/willie-wong) states [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50527/314569) that there exists a constant $C$ (which depends a bit on the conventions and also on the dimension and the degree of the forms) such that
$$(3)\qquad\qquad v\lrcorner\gamma = C \star(v^\flat\wedge \star\gamma), $$
where $\star$ is the [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator). How can I prove this formula?(which in turn also must determine the exact value of $C$)

I apologize if these formulas are easy to prove (I collected some "trivialities" usually left as an exercise to the reader), but I find them very pretty and somewhat cryptic, I'm not really sure on how should I proceed. Also, it seems that nobody actually wants to write out all the (possibly gory) details (or at least to explain them), so any help or reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think at least $(1)$ and $(2)$ are easy to see if you write everything down in terms of components in an orthonormal frame - just need to remember that when $\beta$ is alternating, $\langle \beta , T \rangle$ is (up to a constant depending on convention) equal to $\langle \beta, \mathrm{Alt}(T) \rangle$.

Comment: Just a remark: All of these identities are statements about vector spaces $V$ (and its dual $V^*$ and exterior powers $\Lambda^kV$) equipped with an inner product: the operators $\lrcorner$, $\wedge$, and $\star$ all make sense in this context.  My only point is that you don't need to bring manifolds or bundles into this.

Comment: I actually figured out how to prove $(2)$ directly, I'll post it later.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Of course, you are right, but I still decided to put it in this context because that is the natural setting where these questions appeared to me in the first place (and it also gets more attention than just a multilinear algebra task)

Comment: For $(1)$, you may find useful the proof of the proposition I stated on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4601974/394668).